# Service Certificate WCF Service

Tags: wcf, nettcpbinding, workgroup

I encountered a problem whereby the WCF Service Host does not detect the existence of the service certificate that is needed to host a WCF service.

**System.InvalidOperationException: The service certificate is not provided. Specify a service certificate in ServiceCredentials.**

Service Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="announcementBehavior">
      <!--The following behavior attribute is required to enable WCF serialization of large data sets -->
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
      <serviceDiscovery>
        <announcementEndpoints>
          <endpoint kind="announcementEndpoint"
        address="net.tcp://localhost:8005/Announcement"
        binding="netTcpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="RequestReplyNetTcpBinding"/>
        </announcementEndpoints>
      </serviceDiscovery>
      <serviceThrottling
              maxConcurrentCalls="1500"
              maxConcurrentSessions="1500"
              maxConcurrentInstances="1500"/>
      <serviceCredentials>
        <serviceCertificate findValue="WCFServer"
                            storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                            storeName="TrustedPeople"
                            x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
        <clientCertificate>
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust" trustedStoreLocation="LocalMachine" revocationMode="NoCheck"/>
        </clientCertificate>
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
 </serviceBehaviors>  
 </behaviors> 
 <service name="Test2ServLib.IService1"
   behaviorConfiguration="announcementBehavior">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8006/Service1"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint binding="netTcpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="RequestReplyNetTcpBinding"
              contract="Test2ServLib.IService1"
              behaviorConfiguration="LargeEndpointBehavior" />
        <bindings>  
            <netTcpBinding>  
                <binding name = "RequestReplyNetTcpBinding">  
                    <security>  
                        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />  
                    </security>  
                </binding>  
            </netTcpBinding>  
        </bindings>  
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Make sure this certificate exists on the computer and run the WCF service as an administrator.

Comment: The certificate exists on the computer

Comment: and it is being run as an admin

Comment: There is no problem with your configuration file, so this is because the service cannot find the certificate. Try to use FindByThumbprint to find the certificate.